# Why is "there" pronounced あそこ and not just あこ?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Irregularity of あ-series in demonstratives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4815/irregularity-of-%e3%81%82-series-in-demonstratives)

Maybe this is a little hard to answer, but I'm curious why the typical これ/それ/あれ pattern doesn't apply to ここ/そこ/あそこ. Is anyone familiar with any etymological reasoning behind choosing あそこ as a reading over あこ?

Comment: I am sorry to say that I don't think this is a very good question. Whys rarely are. In most cases languages are just arbitrary rules development over time, rather than things with clear reasoning behind them.